# Selecting vertices in a convex polygon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-optimization

Given $n$ vertices of a  convex polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$, selecting two points that are furthest apart is done by finding the diameter in a convex polygon. But how can one select three vertices such that the minimum distance between them is maximized?

Yes, it can be done by iterating over all possible combinations of three vertices which will take $O(n^3)$ time. Is it possible to do it in less time? —maybe in $O(n^2\log n)$ time.

EDIT: I believe that finding k vertices such that minimum distance is maximized is a difficult problem.

Comment: Just a point of clarification: I understand (and edited accordingly) that the question asks for selecting points *from the vertices* of the polygon. If you allow points anywhere on the polygon boundary, the distance could be larger. For a simple example consider the unit square, with distance=1 with three vertices, but approx 1.035 with suitable three points on the boundary.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen yes it is true for unit square polygon, but for a convex polygon finding three points is like finding another convex polygon consisting of three vertices such that minimum distance is maximized.

Comment: Suppose the vertices are numbered from $1$ to $n$ going around the convex shape. Start with the triple $(1,2,3)$. Then move from the triple $(a,b,c)$ to whichever triple of $(a+1,b,c)$, $(a,b+1,c)$ or $(a,b,c+1)$ has the largest minimum distance. Continue until you hit $(n-2, n-1, n)$, which will be after $3n-3$ moves. That algorithm is fast and looks promising — will it always pass through the maximal option?

Comment: @MattF. Are you considering only convex edge as a distance for your algorithm? It seems like that.  We need to consider between two points, even there does not exist any convex edge... This is  what I got it from your algorithm

Comment: My proposed algorithm would go from $(1,2,3)$ to $(1,2,4)$, where the line segment from $2$ to $4$ would ordinarily be in the interior of the convex body everywhere except at the endpoints.

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: A similar problem asks for a maximum-*area* triangle spanned by three vertices of a polygon. For this problem fast algorithms are known (but also some erroneous ones). Of course the maximization problem is different, but at least one could check these for algorithm ideas: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.11035 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621364/how-to-find-largest-triangle-in-convex-hull-aside-from-brute-force-search

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Thanks for sharing the link...

Comment: @MattF. Article shared by Kohonen uses a similar idea for finding a triangle with the largest area . You can check it too.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen those linked counterexamples on p 5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.11035.pdf are remarkably colorful.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in time $O(n^2\log{n})$ is easy: use binary search over the answer (there are at most $n^2$ possible answers) and for a given answer the question boils down to finding a triangle in a graph on $n$ vertices (with edges between any two points at distance at least $d$ from each other). For a general graph this takes time $O(n^\omega)$ but here it is much easier: Fix one vertex, among other vertices select those at distance at least $d$ from it and check is the diameter of this set is at least $d$. We can compute diameter in time $O(n)$ since vertices are already in a convex position. So total time is $\log{n}$ for the binary search, $n$ for selecting one vertex and $n$ for computing diameter of the set of points at distance at least $d$ from it. This gives total complexity $O(n^2\log{n})$.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Sadhu et al. (2020) report an $O(n^2)$ algorithm for a closely related problem: Finding a triangle inside a convex polygon so as to maximize the shortest side of the triangle.

Note than unlike the present problem, Sadhu et al. do not require all three vertices of the triangle to be vertices of the original polygon. However, they do prove that at least *one* of the vertices of such a triangle will coincide with a vertex of the polygon.

I have not checked their algorithm, but here is a verbatim quote of their main theorem. ($\delta$ refers to the shortest side of the triangle.)

**Theorem 4.** Given a convex polygon $P$, the triangle $\Delta$ inside $P$ with longest $\delta(\Delta)$ can be obtained in $O(n^2)$ time.

*Sadhu, Sanjib; Roy, Sasanka; Nandi, Soumen; Nandy, Subhas C.; Roy, Suchismita*, [**Efficient algorithm for computing the triangle maximizing the length of its smallest side inside a convex polygon**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0129054120500173), Int. J. Found. Comput. Sci. 31, No. 4, 421-443 (2020). [ZBL1462.68209](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1462.68209).

A preliminary version of their work appeared in ICCSA 2017. It may be easier to access, but there they report only an $O(n^2 \log n)$ algorithm.

- https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-62395-5_35